# Are Capital Ships always grade A, and is there a grade S

Tags: no-mans-sky

In the NEXT update I have noticed that the "free" Capital ship that I was given after saving it from Pirates was a class A capital ship, is this always the case that the Capital ship is grade A or was I just really lucky? Also is there a grade S Capital ship available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From experience, I obtained my capital ship the same way, and it was an S class.

[image: S class freighter]

The [wiki page](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Starship_Catalogue_-_Freighter) also mentions that they can be an S class:

> As of Atlas Rises, Freighters also receive an A/B/C/S class designation

So yes, you can obtain an S class freighter via saving it like you and I did, and yes S class freighters exist, as well as A, B, and C classes.

Comment: I was unfortunate and obtained a C class freighter as my capital ship. I wonder if it would be possible to decline the freebie and continue saving freighter until your capital ship is an S rank

Comment: I have read that you can decline and keep looking till you find the right one, so keep looking @Wondercricket